# Java and android: a kind of listener

Tags: java, android, listener

Thank you for dedicate me few minutes :)
I'm trying to do something that maybe it's not possible in the way I'm doing it :D
Look at this (wrong) code:

```
public boolean myFunction() {
        myClassA.setOnResultSet( new myClassB() {

            @Override
            public Boolean onResultSet() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return (Boolean)myClassA.getResult();
            }
        });


        Intent myIntent = new Intent(mInstanceContext, MediaPlayerService.class);
        myIntent.setAction("isThatParticularStateTrueOrFalse");
        mInstanceContext.startService(myIntent);

}
```

There are the last 3 lines of the code that ask something to a service. The service will save the result of the question in a singleton class X so that the first class (the which one that I wrote you upon) can read the result from the class X.
However there's a problem that I think is caused by the fact that I'm working with a service: the service is quite slow so I cannot get the result of my question immediately. This is way the singleton class call the method onResultSet() when the result is set. (That's a kind of listener that I'm trying to implement by myself :D )
But than how can made the function myFunction() return the result? Unfortunately I cannot make the function onResultSet() returning the result: this is what I tried to do in code that I write you, but, as you can see, it make error. I understand why I receive the error but as a newbye I cannot see a solution without using broadcaster (which if possible I don't want to use).
Thank you all :)

Comment: Now I understand and I'm solving it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)? and if you need to post updates to your main UI thread you can use [Handlers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Comment: The problem is not that I have to wait for the result :D For me it's ok to wait, but anyway, at the moment I'm not able to get the result :D

Comment: This is proper approach towards any kind of work that does not returns immediately to the main thread. So, once you follow this rather than creating your own system, it would make things easy.

Comment: I'll see it hoping to implent it with a service ;)

Comment: But before I'll try I want to say you that also if I wait, at the moment, I'm not able to get the result :D

Comment: Open a new clearer question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267349/android-get-result-from-a-service