# Android: get result from a service

Tags: android, service, return

I have android service which I need to return a result after it has been started.
So:

1) I start the service

2) The service does something

3) The service returns a result

I thought that maybe I can use a singleton class to take the result. I created a singleton class in order to make the service save the result in it and then take the result from the service by an activity. Here there's the code of the class:

```
public class Result {

    //SIGLETON DECLARATION

    private static Result mInstance = null;

    public static Result getInstance() { 
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new Result();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    private Result() {
    }

    //CODE

    Object result;
    boolean resultIsSet = false;

    public void deletePreviousResult() {
        this.result = null;
        resultIsSet = false;
    }

    public void setResult(Object result) {
        Log.w("result", "setResult");
        this.result = result;
        resultIsSet = true;
    }

    public Object getResult() {
        Log.w("result", "getResult");
        while(resultIsSet == false) {}
        return this.result;
    }
```

Here's the code that I use to get the result:

```
public int getInfo() {
    Result.getInstance().deletePreviousResult();
    //start the service and ask to save the result in singleton class
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(mInstanceContext, MediaPlayerService.class);
    myIntent.setAction("getInfo");
    mInstanceContext.startService(myIntent);
    //take the result
    return (Integer) Result.getInstance().getResult();
}
```

What is doing in `onStartCommand` is:

```
 Result.getInstance().setResult(mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
```

where `mMediaPlayer` is a MediaPlayer object.

However the problem is that if `setResult` is also supposed to be called in `onStartCommand`, it is never called! Why? Is it my approach wrong?

Comment: Can you share the code for your onStartCommand ?

Comment: Of course, what it do is this:
Result.getInstance().setResult(mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
where mMediaPlayer is a MediaPlayer object ;)

Comment: Just to cross check, have you declared the service in manifest? What base class your services extends Service or IntentService or any other?

Comment: It extends Service and it is declared :)

Answer (score 1):

This code you have in `getInfo()`:

```
mInstanceContext.startService(myIntent);
//take the result
return (Integer) Result.getInstance().getResult();
```

assumes that when you call `startService()` the service is started and `onStartCommand()` is called **synchronously** so that in the next statement you can get the result using `Result.getInstance().getResult()`.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work that way. Calling `startService()` isn't like calling a method on an object. What you do when you call `startService()` is that you tell Android that you want that service to be started **at the next available moment**. Since `onStartCommand()` in your service needs to be called on the main thread, usually this means that Android will start your service and call `onStartCommand()` at the next time when Android gets control of the main thread (ie: when all your activity methods have returned). In any case, you can't determine when the service will be started or when `onStartCommand()` will be called. It is an **asynchronous** call, so you need to rely on a **callback** mechanism. This means that you need to write some kind of callback method that the service can call when it has done the work and wants to return the result to you.

There are various ways to do this. You could have the service send an Intent to your activity. You could have the service broadcast an Intent with the results. You could bind to the service and register a callback listener (see developer documentation for bound services). There are probably other ways too.

Comment: Adding to what you mentioned, 'return (Integer) Result.getInstance().getResult();' results in an infinite loop because 'getResult()' checks if 'resultIsSet' is true ; only then does it return the value of 'result'. Now, the funny part is, 'resultIsSet' can be set to true in the 'onStartCommand' of the service. But a service runs in the main thread of its application and the application is currently looping infinitely in 'getResult()'. So this is kind of a deadlock. This is where callbacks come in. Instead of checking in a loop infinitely, a service can broadcast an intent.

Comment: You could probably run the getResult() in a background thread, so that it doesn't block the main thread from running your service. That way things stay simple?